# XSLT: all elements to div elements with class attribute = original element name

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've got a xml in the following form (but much larger..)

```
<entry>
    <lemma>coaster</lemma>
    <sense>
        <trans>Untersetzer</trans>
    </sense>
</entry>
```

What I want to get by xsl-transformation is this:

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="lemma>coaster</div>
    <div class="sense">
        <div class="trans">Untersetzer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not that complicated: Transform all elements to div elements with class attribute = original element name.
Could anybody please give me a hint how an appropriate XSL should look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that (XSLT 1.0) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <div class="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the stylesheet skip the attributes it encounters.

**EDIT after comment**

If you want to keep attributes, you just have to skip any `class` attributes (because you create a new one). For example like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <div class="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:if test="name() != 'class'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>            
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And what if you want to output class attributes to somithing like `attr-class`? Could you also explain it a little please?

Comment: Use the second xslt, change the class attribute to a attr-class attribute in the first template and change the test in the if statement in the second template with name() != 'attr-class'. The second template is here to avoid problem if some attributes named 'attr-class' exists in the original XML file. Hope this helps.